# python dataframe combine two boolean columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, logical-operators

I have a dataframe. I am performing forward and backward substraction. Later, perform a comparison and produce boolean outputs. Next, I want to perform logical and on these results and produce one result.

Code:

```
xdf = pd.DataFrame({'data':range(0,6)},index=pd.date_range('2022-06-03 00:00:00', '2022-06-03 00:00:25', freq='5s'))

# perform 1 row backward substraction
bs = xdf['data'].diff(1).abs().le(1)

# perform 1 row forward substraction
fs= xdf['data'].diff(-1).abs().le(1)


bs = 
2022-06-03 00:00:00    False
2022-06-03 00:00:05     True
2022-06-03 00:00:10     True
2022-06-03 00:00:15     True
2022-06-03 00:00:20     True
2022-06-03 00:00:25     True
Freq: 5S, Name: data, dtype: bool

fs = 

2022-06-03 00:00:00     True
2022-06-03 00:00:05     True
2022-06-03 00:00:10     True
2022-06-03 00:00:15     True
2022-06-03 00:00:20     True
2022-06-03 00:00:25    False
```

Present and expected output:

```
xdf['validation'] = np.logical_and(sa,sb)
2022-06-03 00:00:00    False
2022-06-03 00:00:05     True
2022-06-03 00:00:10     True
2022-06-03 00:00:15     True
2022-06-03 00:00:20     True
2022-06-03 00:00:25    False
Freq: 5S, Name: data, dtype: bool
```

The output is correct and this is what I am expecting. My question, is there a way I can compute all the above (forward substraction and backward substraction) in a single code of line?

Comment: You are testing whether the `abs(a-b)<1` It really does not matter whether it is `b-a` or `a-b` since you are doing the `abs`. Hence just calculate the back difference and use that, while changing the first and last values to False since we should not have those values

Comment: @onyambu I posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72494309/python-dataframe-timeseries-check-if-value-changed-more-than-x-in-last-n-rows-an

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try loop the `[1,-1]` and use `np.logical_and.reduce`

```py
xdf['validation'] = np.logical_and.reduce([xdf['data'].diff(x).abs().le(1) for x in [1,-1]])
```

```
print(xdf)

                     data  validation
2022-06-03 00:00:00     0       False
2022-06-03 00:00:05     1        True
2022-06-03 00:00:10     2        True
2022-06-03 00:00:15     3        True
2022-06-03 00:00:20     4        True
2022-06-03 00:00:25     5       False
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use a rolling max, then check whether the max is ≤ your target:

```
xdf['validation'] = xdf['data'].diff(-1).abs().rolling(2).max().le(1)
```

output:

```
                     data  validation
2022-06-03 00:00:00     0       False
2022-06-03 00:00:05     1        True
2022-06-03 00:00:10     2        True
2022-06-03 00:00:15     3        True
2022-06-03 00:00:20     4        True
2022-06-03 00:00:25     5       False
```

Comment: But it is only doing forward substraction. correct? or is it covering both sides? Can you you bit explanation. This seems to be simple and straight forward. I missing the logic here.

Comment: as pointed out by @onyambu, `abs(a-b)` is the same as `abs(b-a)` so the order doesn't matter, what matters is the shift. So in this case it is strictly equivalent. It wouldn't be with a non symmetrical operator. Similarly, using the `max` is specific because we use `le` later. For a `ge` we would need to use `min` ;)

Comment: In my code, I am basically checking if the data changed within a value in a given time, say 10s, not more than that. I am checking this before and after. In your code, you are doing the rolling(2). Is it doing the same thing? or am I just checking just instantaneous value before 1 min and now and not in between value? I want to check all the samples in the last 1 min and see if all values less than the defined.

Comment: Hi I posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72494309/python-dataframe-timeseries-check-if-value-changed-more-than-x-in-last-n-rows-an