# python dataframe timeseries check if value changed more than x in last n rows and forward n rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a sunlight data coming from the field. I am checking if the sunlight changed more than a value in last 1 min and future 1 min. Below I am giving an example case. Where I am checking if the data value changed more than 4 in the last 10s.
code:

```
xdf = pd.DataFrame({'data':np.random.randint(10,size=10)},index=pd.date_range('2022-06-03 00:00:00', '2022-06-03 00:00:45', freq='5s'))
# here data frequency 5s, so, to check last 10s
# I have to consider present row and last 2 rows
# Perform rolling max and min value for 3 rows
nrows = 3
# Allowable change
ac = 4
xdf['back_max'] = xdf['data'].rolling(nrows).max()
xdf['back_min'] = xdf['data'].rolling(nrows).min()
xdf['back_min_max_dif'] = (xdf['back_max'] - xdf['back_min'])
xdf['back_<4'] = (xdf['back_max'] - xdf['back_min']).abs().le(ac)
print(xdf)

## Again repeat the above for the future nrows
## Don't know how?
```

expected output:

```
                     data  back_max  back_min  back_min_max_dif  back_<4
2022-06-03 00:00:00     7       NaN       NaN               NaN    False
2022-06-03 00:00:05     7       NaN       NaN               NaN    False
2022-06-03 00:00:10     5       7.0       5.0               2.0     True
2022-06-03 00:00:15     8       8.0       5.0               3.0     True
2022-06-03 00:00:20     6       8.0       5.0               3.0     True
2022-06-03 00:00:25     2       8.0       2.0               6.0    False
2022-06-03 00:00:30     3       6.0       2.0               4.0     True
2022-06-03 00:00:35     1       3.0       1.0               2.0     True
2022-06-03 00:00:40     5       5.0       1.0               4.0     True
2022-06-03 00:00:45     5       5.0       1.0               4.0     True
```

Is there way I can simplify the above procedure? Also, I have to perform rolling max for future nrows, and how?

Comment: It's pretty much what I'd do. However, I'd skip attaching the intermediate columns to the dataframe. Also, do you need the two separate values for future and past changes?

Comment: Unrelated, there's an option of rolling on time windows as well. It might be slower than rolling by rows, however.

Comment: @QuangHoang I really appreciate your comment. I feel like there is an improvement in my coding. I don't want those columns, take unnecessary memory. I just wanted to show here and explain better. However, I have done it for the past. Question is, how to do it for future?

Comment: @QuangHoang also `.rolling(-3)` is not working. I thought it would do the forward rolling. How do we do forward rolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future/forward roll, you can roll on the reversed data. This might not work with time-window roll:

```
rolling = xdf['data'].rolling(nrows)
xdf['pass_<'] = (rolling.max()-rolling.min()).le(ac)

future_roll = xdf['data'][::-1].rolling(nrows)
xdf['future_<'] = future_roll.max().sub(future_roll.min()).le(ac)
```

Output:

```
                     data  pass_<  future_<
2022-06-03 00:00:00     7   False      True
2022-06-03 00:00:05     7   False      True
2022-06-03 00:00:10     5    True      True
2022-06-03 00:00:15     8    True     False
2022-06-03 00:00:20     6    True      True
2022-06-03 00:00:25     2   False      True
2022-06-03 00:00:30     3    True      True
2022-06-03 00:00:35     1    True      True
2022-06-03 00:00:40     5    True     False
2022-06-03 00:00:45     5    True     False
```

Comment: I thought about it. Really nice solution. Guess what: we can actually roll pass_result back and don't have to do the rolling max and min again for the future. Am I correct? Suppose, in your answer, look at the 2 and 3 third columns. Both are same. Rolling the 2 column 3 rows backwards give the 3 column.

Comment: Yes, you're totally correct, forward roll is essentially `shift(-nrows).rolling(nrows).do_something().shift()`. But you're gonna miss some of the beginning/end windows.

Comment: Sounds good. I am doing this `xdf['forward_<4'] = xdf['back_<4'][::-3]` but getting mix of True and NaNs. Am I wrong?

Comment: do you mean `xdf['back<4].shfit(-3)`? ortherwise you would have the same column due to index alignment. Another thing is we can do this because `min/max` are direction-agnostic. Gotta go the `shift` route if it's cumsum, for example.

Comment: Oh, `[::-3]` meaning you reverse and skip 3 rows at a time. So yeah, you're getting mixed NaN results (2 out of 3 rows?). So it's wrong.

Comment: Looks like I am wrong. I am curious here. is `[::-1]` is fixed irrespective of the `nrows`. I thought I should be doing `[::-nrows]`. Looks like I misunderstood. Can you explain bit here what exactly is doing `[::-1]` doing. I also computed `xdf['data_forward']=xdf['data'][::-1]` but the data looks same as `xdf['data']`. I am surprised.

Comment: Yes,  1)`[::-1]` means reverse only. `[::-3]` does the same thing as `[::3]` except to the reversed data. 2) re `data_forward`, index alignment...

Comment: One more question: `futureroll = xdf['data'][::-1].rolling(nrows)` here it should be `(-nrows)`. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, just `nrows`...